# Modify Oracle Package code

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I have added two fields to a table called CartRequests. We store JSON text in this table sent from our e-commerce package for each of our online orders. This helps us to be able to rebuild orders that fail for any reason. I am adding these 2 fields to facilitate faster searches because, currently, we have to only search the json (CR_JSON) text for values and it takes anywhere from 30 secs to a minute to find anything using a like clause. Most of the time, we are searching for either the CustomerID or OrderID.

I have the following package that puts the sent JSON into the CartRequests table, it was written 
by another developer more familiar with PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CIC3.CartJSON AS
    gCr_id          number;
    gRequestMsg     varchar2(32000);
    gResponseMsg    varchar2(32000);
    gMessageJSON    w_MessageJSON_t;
    gJSON           JSON.JSONStructObj;

    procedure SaveRequest is
    begin
        select CartRequestsSeq.nextval into gCr_id from dual;
        insert into CartRequests (cr_id, cr_date ,cr_json) values (gCr_id, sysdate, gRequestMsg);
    end;

    procedure ExtractRequest is
        i       number;
        vJSON   JSON.JSONStructObj;
    begin
        i:=-1;
        vJSON:=JSON.String2JSON(gRequestMsg);
        NewJMessageJSON(gMessageJSON,vJSON,i);

        gJSON:=JSON.String2JSON(gMessageJSON.ObjectSent);

        update CartRequests set
                cr_CartTime=gMessageJSON.CartTime,
                cr_ObjectSent=gMessageJSON.ObjectSent 
               -- ***************************************************************
               -- I'd like to add these fields but getting following errors:
               -- PLS-00487 (39: 27): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'OBJECTSENT'
               -- ORA-00904 (39: 27): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "GMESSAGEJSON"."OBJECTSENT"."CUSTOMERID": invalid identifier
               -- ***************************************************************
               -- cr_OrderID=gMessageJSON.ObjectSent.OrderID,      -- Adding this field
               -- cr_CustomerID=gMessageJSON.ObjectSent.CustomerID -- Adding this field
        where cr_id=gCr_id;            
    end;

END CartJSON;
/
```

How can I add these 2 fields with no errors?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type CIC3.W_MESSAGEJSON_T as object (
     CartTime       Varchar2(30),
     ObjectSent     Varchar2(4000),
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PLS-00487 (39: 27): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'OBJECTSENT'
ORA-00904 (39: 27): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "GMESSAGEJSON"."OBJECTSENT"."CUSTOMERID": invalid identifier
```

The PL/SQL compiler error message above indicates that variable `gMessageJSON` (that is type of `w_MessageJSON_t`) doesn't have a member `ObjectSent` that would have member `OrderID` or `CustomerID`. You don't show us `w_MessageJSON_t` (could be an object type or a record) so it's impossible to say anything more precise.

Maybe the correct syntax would be `cr_OrderID = gMessageJSON.OrderID`?

Comment: I think I'm now beginning to see why. Gonna have to parse the ObjectSent...Darn it.

Comment: @MB34 Are you saying that `OrderID` and `CustomerID` are part of `ObjectSend` JSON (string) ? One possible option is that you parse the ids from `ObjectSend` to member variables at the time you create the object. Then you can use them as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: The thing is that the parsing code will crash because it is expecting the JSON to be formatted exactly the same as it should be. I will get the developer to fix this instead. Thanks.